# pandas json_normalize generates only one big row

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a JSON-file and would like to parse it into a pandas DataFrame. I would like to have the following structure:

ID    | Event               | Site                         | ...

Game1 | "Rated Bullet game" | https://lichess.org/spTUcy1Z | ...

Game2 | "Rated Blitz game"  | https://lichess.org/kh6FJkyS | ...

However using `df = pd.json_normalize(all_rows)`, the df looks like this:

---| Game1.Event        | Game1.Site                     | ...

0   | Rated Bullet game  | https://lichess.org/spTUcy1Z   | ...

The JSON looks like this:

```
{
  "Game1": {
    "Event": "Rated Bullet game",
    "Site": "https://lichess.org/spTUcy1Z",
    "Date": "2020.05.01",
    "Round": "-",
    "White": "AaravShah25",
    "Black": "daksh_badhwar",
    "Result": "0-1",
    "UTCDate": "2020.05.01",
    "UTCTime": "04:55:40",
    "WhiteElo": "1360",
    "BlackElo": "1342",
    "WhiteRatingDiff": "-10",
    "BlackRatingDiff": "+6",
    "ECO": "C56",
    "Opening": "Italian Game: Scotch Gambit, Nakhmanson Gambit",
    "TimeControl": "60+0",
    "Termination": "Normal",
    "moves": "1. e4 { [%clk 0:01:00] } e5 { [%clk 0:01:00] } 2. d4 { [%clk 0:00:59] } Nc6 { [%clk 0:01:00] } 3. Nf3 { [%clk 0:00:58] } exd4 { [%clk 0:00:59] } 4. Bc4 { [%clk 0:00:58] } Nf6 { [%clk 0:00:56] } 5. O-O { [%clk 0:00:58] } Nxe4 { [%clk 0:00:54] } 6. Nc3 { [%clk 0:00:58] } Bc5 { [%clk 0:00:53] } 7. Re1 { [%clk 0:00:58] } O-O { [%clk 0:00:52] } 8. h3 { [%clk 0:00:56] } dxc3 { [%clk 0:00:50] } 0-1"
  },
  "Game2": {
    "Event": "Rated Blitz game",
    "Site": "https://lichess.org/kh6FJkyS",
    "Date": "2020.05.01",
    "Round": "-",
    "White": "Quggai",
    "Black": "vasiukov",
    "Result": "1-0",
    "UTCDate": "2020.05.01",
    "UTCTime": "07:41:06",
    "WhiteElo": "2292",
    "BlackElo": "2210",
    "WhiteRatingDiff": "+5",
    "BlackRatingDiff": "-4",
    "ECO": "C56",
    "Opening": "Italian Game: Scotch Gambit, Nakhmanson Gambit",
    "TimeControl": "180+0",
    "Termination": "Normal",
    "moves": "1. e4 { [%clk 0:03:00] } e5 { [%clk 0:03:00] } 2. Bc4 { [%clk 0:02:59] } Nf6 { [%clk 0:02:58] } 3. d4 { [%clk 0:02:58] } Nc6 { [%clk 0:02:51] } 4. Nf3 { [%clk 0:02:56] } exd4 { [%clk 0:02:48] } 5. O-O { [%clk 0:02:55] } Nxe4 { [%clk 0:02:46] } 6. Nc3 { [%clk 0:02:54] } dxc3 { [%clk 0:02:43] } 7. Bxf7+ { [%clk 0:02:48] } Kxf7 { [%clk 0:02:41] } 8. Qd5+ { [%clk 0:02:48] } Ke8 { [%clk 0:02:16] } 9. Re1 { [%clk 0:02:47] } Ne7 { [%clk 0:02:13] } 10. Rxe4 { [%clk 0:02:45] } c6 { [%clk 0:02:08] } 11. Qd6 { [%clk 0:02:30] } h6 { [%clk 0:01:32] } 12. Qg6# { [%clk 0:02:18] } 1-0"
  },
...
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The structure of this JSON looks like it could be easily transformed into dataframe using default dataframe constructor:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(all_rows)
```

You can also use [.transform (or just .T)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.T.html) function to change data orientation:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(all_rows).T
```

If there are a lot of nesting objects in this JSON, you can make dataframe from the dictionary values using json_normalize and then set the correct index:

```py
df = pd.json_normalize(list(all_rows.values()))
df.index = all_rows.keys()
```